# IBM Watson Assistant define context variable in slot

Tags: watson, watson-conversation

I cannot figure out how to define an optional slot to define a custom context variable from the combination of two entities. It is something like the image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slot "Check for" looks for a single returning value if it exists. If it does, then it stores it in the context variable you set in "Save it as".

In the case above, you would need to separate `@activity:compay` and `@location` into separate checks.

Once those are met, then in the "Respond with", click on the context editor, and put your `activity = 1` there.